# Adding a range to select from in textbox on C# Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want my textbox to look like the picture bellow where I can select between the options inside but for some reason I am not able to figure it out. I'm using Visual studio for C#
[The textbox under years of service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF4wX.png)

Comment: it is a listbox where the labels and values are separate

Comment: ohh ok yea makes sense i didnt know that was a thing lol sorry im very new to this

Answer (score 2):

It's ListBox. you can select it under the Toolbox window.

[image]